# Minecraft, villages doesn't breed or farm

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In the following picture, there is a villager breeder, but it doesnt work. Villagers doesnt breed or farm the potatoes, i tried almost everything at this point still nothing works, what the problem?

Minecraft Version : 1.17

[image]

Comment: I'm not 100% sure of this because I haven't played on java in a while and I don't really know the mechanics, but I believe the reason they aren't breeding is because they can't access the beds you put in the far middle. Try opening that up and see if they can start breeding.

Comment: You aren't getting far with *two* potatoes. Villagers won't magick crops to plant out of thin air.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By your image, it seems that the villagers do not pick up the food. This is most likely because the game rule `mobGriefing` is set to `false`. This is commonly used to disable creeper explosions from breaking blocks, but it also affects other things, like your villagers. The full list is pasted here, from the [official wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Game_rule):

> When false, prevents:
>
> - All mobs from:
>
>   - Trampling crops.
>   - Trampling turtle eggs.
>   - Picking up items.
>   - Destroying blocks.
> - Blazes from creating fire or lighting campfires.
> - Creepers from destroying blocks when they explode, although they still damage entities.
> - End crystals from destroying blocks when they explode, although they still damage entities.
> - The ender dragon from destroying blocks, causing it to just fly through them instead.
> - Endermen from picking up or placing blocks.
> - Evoker from turning blue sheep red.
> - Foxes from picking sweet berries from a sweet berry bush.
> - Ghast fireballs from exploding blocks and creating fire. They still damage entities.
> - Piglins from attempting to barter by picking up dropped items; using the item on them still works.
> - Rabbits from eating carrot crops.
> - Ravagers from destroying crops and leaves.
> - Sheep from turning grass blocks into dirt, but does not prevent the regrowth of wool. They still act as if they are eating the grass and regrow their wool upon doing so, but the grass remains and the grass breaking sound does not play.
> - Silverfish from hiding in stone and destroying those blocks when hatching.
> - Snow golems from creating snow trails.
> - Villagers from farming and picking up items. However, they can still open doors and throw items.
> - The wither and its heads from destroying blocks with their explosions. Entities are still damaged, and a wither rose drops as an item.
> - Zombies from breaking doors and attacking turtle eggs.
>   Has no effect on the player.

You can re-enable mobGriefing with `/gamerule mobGriefing true`.